# How do I compute the sum of bitwise operator results in the following case?

Tags: c

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 512,b = 32;
    int c = a>>2 + b<<2;
    printf("%d",c);

    return 0;
}
```

The result I'd expect isn't 512 and rather 128 (a>>2) + 128 (b<<2) as the result. Why is the output 512? I understand that arithmetic + operator has higher precedence but where does the brackets land? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You compiler should have warned you about operator precedence. You need to change `a>>2 + b<<2` to `(a >> 2) + (b << 2)`.

Comment: So if you understand the precedence, what is the problem? It is evaluated as `(a>>(2+b)) << 2). Which is undefined behavior, as you are shifting more than the type width.

Comment: I understood the precedence of plus but wasn't sure about undefined behavior due to shifting more than the type width. Thanks for that info @EugeneSh.

Answer (score 1):

[Operator precedence in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm) states that additive operators have a higher precedence than shifting operators, if you want the expected output of 256 you will need to use parenthesis to force shifting to take place first. So,
`int c = a>>2 + b<<2;` becomes `int c = (a>>2) + (b<<2);`

As stated in the comments (by @Eugene Sh.), currently it is evaluated as `(a>>(2+b)) << 2)` and that is undefined behavior, as you are shifting more than the type width.